# uploading large file c# http post

Tags: c#, file, upload, byte

I have a requirement to upload large files (upto 2GB) from my .NET web application to a java web service which in turn consumes a .jar file.
The java webservice API accepts MultipartFormDataContent as its parameter.

Problem I am facing is, I am unable to load the entire 2GB into a byte array as it throws "SystemOutOfMemoryException" when I attempt to upload a file anything larger that 300MB.

I also tried BufferedReader, StreamWriter but in vain.
Provided my code below for your reference:

```
public bool SendMessage(Dictionary<string, byte[]> files, string fromAddress, string toAddresses, string ccAddresses, string subject, string body)
        {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, long> fileSizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
       Dictionary<string, ByteArrayContent> fileContent = new Dictionary<string, ByteArrayContent>();
       HttpContent fileSizesContent = null;

            try
            {
                HttpContent messageContent = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(new
                {
                    to = toAddress,
                    cc = ccAddresses,
                    subject = subject,
                    body = "Test"                   
                }));

                if (files != null)
                {
                    foreach (var entry in files)
                    {
                        fileSizes.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value.Length);
                        fileContent.Add(entry.Key, new ByteArrayContent(entry.Value));
                    }
                    fileSizesContent = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(fileSizes));
                }

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        if (fileContent.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var entry in fileContent)
                            {
                                formData.Add(entry.Value, "attachments", entry.Key);
                            }
                            formData.Add(fileSizesContent, "fileSizes");
                        }
                        formData.Add(messageContent, "message");

                        var response = client.PostAsync(<java web service url>, formData).Result;

                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Issue is: I am unable to opulate the parameter ByteArrayContent as it throws SystemOutOfMemoeyException for files >300MB.

Please help me out.

Thanks.